# Python textual creating a CSS programmatically

Tags: python, css, dynamic, textual

I'm trying to create a Python Textual Widget that can be reused on a lot of places (basic a search widget). It should have a grid with the title, any number of labels with inputs, and a last line for the buttons (Search and Cancel).
While I was able to create the Widget, whenever I reuse it, it seems that the CSS I used is being ignored, and only the first CSS is actually applied, can someone please help me out?
Here's the code for the Widget:

```
from textual.app import ComposeResult
from textual.screen import ModalScreen
from textual.widgets import Button, Static, Input
from textual.containers import Grid
from textual import events


class DSASearchDialog(ModalScreen[dict]):
    """Generic dialog to create a search dialog. If you need anything more complex, please write your own dialog"""
    dialog_title = 'Sample Search Dialog'
    dialog_inputs = [
        {
            'name': 'Sample Label 1',
            'id': 'dsa-search-sample-name-label-1',
            'classes': 'dsa-search-label',
            'input-classes': 'optional',
            'type': 'text'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Sample Label 2',
            'id': 'dsa-search-sample-name-label-2',
            'classes': 'dsa-search-label',
            'input-classes': 'optional',
            'type': 'text'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Sample Label 3',
            'id': 'dsa-search-sample-name-label-3',
            'classes': 'dsa-search-label',
            'input-classes': 'mandatory',
            'type': 'text'
        }
    ]
    
    def build_base_css(self) -> None:
        """Build the base css"""
        # Each input has a height of 3
        input_height = len(self.dialog_inputs)*3
        # plus 4 for the buttons and an extra 3 for the title
        total_height = input_height + 4 + 5
        # Create the rows sizes
        grid_rows_txt = "grid-rows: 3" # title
        # each input
        max_label_length = 10
        for i in range(len(self.dialog_inputs)):
            grid_rows_txt += " 3"
            if len(self.dialog_inputs[i]['name']) > max_label_length:
                max_label_length = len(self.dialog_inputs[i]['name'])+3
        grid_rows_txt += " 4;" #buttons
        self.CSS = ""\
            f"#dsa-search-grid"+" {\n" \
                f"grid-size: 1 {len(self.dialog_inputs)+2};\n"\
                f"{grid_rows_txt}\n"\
                "background: $surface;\n"\
                "border: thick $background 80%;\n"\
                "padding-right: 1;\n"\
                "padding-left: 1;\n"\
                "width: 80;\n"\
                f"height: {total_height};\n"\
            "}\n"\
            ".dsa-input-field {\n"\
                "grid-size: 2;\n"\
                "align: center middle;\n"\
                f"grid-columns: {max_label_length} 1fr;\n"\
            "}"\
            
    
    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        """Dynamically build the dialog based on the amount of inputs"""
        inputs_grid = Grid(
            Static(self.dialog_title, classes='dsa-search-title'),
            id=f"dsa-search-grid"
        )
        # For each input, create the Static and Input widgets, and mount it on the inputs_grid
        for input_data in self.dialog_inputs:
            grid_input = Grid(
                    Static(input_data['name'], classes=input_data['classes'], id='dsa-search-label'),
                    Input(id=f"{input_data['id']}-input", classes=input_data['input-classes']),
                    classes='dsa-input-field',
                    id=input_data['id']
                    )
            inputs_grid.mount(grid_input)
        # Create the buttons
        buttons_grid = Grid(
            Button('Search', id='dsa-search-button', classes='button'),
            Button('Cancel', id='dsa-cancel-button', classes='button', variant='error'),
            id='dsa-search-buttons'
        )
        inputs_grid.mount(buttons_grid)
        # Now yield everything
        yield inputs_grid
        
    def on_key(self, event: events.Key) -> None:
        """When the escape key is pressed, dismiss the modal, when the enter is pressed, execute the search"""
        if event.key == 'escape':
            self.dismiss(None)
        elif event.key == 'enter':
            self.on_button_pressed(Button.Pressed(self.query_one('#dsa-search-button'))) # Call the button pressed method to get the information and dismiss the modal
            event.stop()
    
    def on_button_pressed(self, event: Button.Pressed) -> None:
        """When the search button is pressed, get the information and dismiss the modal"""
        # Get the information
        information = {}
        for input_data in self.dialog_inputs:
            information[input_data['id']] = self.query_one(f'#{input_data["id"]}-input').value
        # Dismiss the modal
        if event.button.id == 'dsa-search-button':
            self.dismiss(information)
        else:
            self.dismiss(None)
        event.stop() # Stop the event propagation so the modal doesn't dismiss itself)
```

And here's how to use it (just a snippet of course):

```
def action_search(self) -> None:
        """Start the generic search dialog, and return the data needed"""
        dlg = DSASearchDialog()
        dlg.dialog_title = "Search Users on DSA"
        dlg.dialog_inputs = [
            {
                'name': 'E-Mail:',
                'id': 'dsa-search-username-label',
                'classes': 'dsa-search-label',
                'input-classes': 'optional',
                'type': 'text'
            },
            {
                'name': 'User ID:',
                'id': 'dsa-search-user-id-label',
                'classes': 'dsa-search-label',
                'input-classes': 'optional',
                'type': 'number'
            }
        ]
        dlg.build_base_css()
        self.app.push_screen(dlg, self.__search_return)
```

If I call that method, it creates the widget correctly, however if I call after this a simpler one (for instance with only one dialog_input), it keeps the same CSS applied, and everything is kind out of order.

I've tried creating a random unique id for each widget (based on the name), and only the first one is still being applied, it seems that the `self.CSS = ...` code block is **not** being called, but the compose is actually trying to call the correct CSS.

Can someone help me out?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically creating your CSS is not advisable. Some of the work you are doing to build the `CSS` attribute can be done in plain CSS. For instance `height` can be set to `auto` which will calculate an optimal height automatically. You can also use `auto` in `grid-columns` to automatically calculate the height.

If there is anything which is too dynamic to express in CSS, it is best done in `on_mount` where you can update styles programatically. The [reference](https://textual.textualize.io/styles/grid/grid_size/) for each style shows how you can set the style via Python.

Comment: Thank you, I still had to calculate the total `height` of the widget, but removing the CSS builder and using `grid-rows: auto;` (instead of `grid-columns`) solved the issue.